# Is using StringBuilder in place of String within function parameters a good idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory, stringbuilder

I need some suggestion on using StringBuilder as against String inside function parameters. The basic structure of my program is as below :

1. There are several functions running sequentially .
2. Based on a Model class. The properties contain Strings and List of strings among other data types.
3. The function parameters contain Model object and other strings as well.
4. The code is running smoothly but I am trying to optimize / reduce memory consumption.
5. One of the techniques employed is to change Strings to StringBuilder wherever necessary (inside the function) and disposing it later.
   This and some other changes have improved the memory and heap size consumption to some extent.

**Where I am not sure is this :**

1. Should I make this change (String to StringBuilder) in parameters also?
2. Does using too many StringBuilder puts unnecessary load on the processor?

I am using the diagnostic tools in visual studio to track but looking for some best practices where I can achieve a balance between memory and CPU consumption.

Already tried :

1. Made those changed (String to StringBuilder) inside function.
2. Gone through the MS documentation
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-8.0

Comment: as always, it depends on the usage. Without code examples, use string where string is appropriate. Generally speaking, string is appropriate for string parameters. You appear to be concerned about something that is probably largely irrelevent.

Comment: If you are excited about StringBuilder, then take a look at `ReadonlySpan<char>` and its use cases.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the usage, StringBuilder performs lot better if you have lots of string Appending. If you have already observed an improvement using StringBuilder, that may be the suitable one for your scenario.

[Performance Benchmarking: String and String Builder](https://dev.to/this-is-learning/performance-benchmarking-string-and-string-builder-3bid#:%7E:text=StringBuilder%20executes%20significantly%20faster%20than,should%20consider%20the%20StringBuilder%20class.)

> StringBuilder executes significantly faster than the String class when
> performing the concatenation or modification operations.
>
> Modifying a String creates a new String in the heap memory. To change
> the content of the String, we should consider the StringBuilder class.

[image]